# manual modified cos in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]Follow-up to [Making a manual picture in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688824)

if instead I modify it as following should I change the domain? As I understood here domain is not mentioned in the sense that no built in function ,almost no any, used instead everything brought up to the picture by defining them.

Exactly I hope picture will be visible. Now that I wanted to change the figure in those ways I was trying to find out if built in cos function should be applied? Since as far as I understood the points denoted and a manual curve adapted to those points. I might understood wrong as well :)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[,scale=1.5,xscale=0.75]
        % axes
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)       -- (2*pi+0.5,0) node[right] {$\theta$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-1.5)    -- (0,1.5)      node[left]  {$Y$};
        % auxiliary lines
        \draw[teal,dashed]      (0,1)       -- (2*pi,1);
        \draw[teal]             (2*pi,-1.5) -- (2*pi,1.5);
        \draw[latex-latex,teal] (pi,0)    -- (pi,1)        node[fill=white,midway] {\small amplitude};
        \draw[latex-latex,teal] (0,-1.25) -- (2*pi,-1.25)  node[fill=white,midway] {\small basic interval $2\pi$};
        \draw[latex-latex,teal] (0,1.25)    -- (2*pi,1.25) node[fill=white,midway,
        yshift=1mm,text width=2cm,
        align=center]      {\small period}; %cycle wavelength;
        % ticks
        \foreach\i in {-1,0,+1}
        \node[left] at (0,\i) {$\i$};
        \node[below]             at (0.5*pi,0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
        \node[below]             at (pi,0)     {$\pi$};
        \node[below,xshift=1mm]  at (1.5*pi,0) {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
        \node[below,fill=white]  at (2*pi,0)   {$2\pi$};
        % cos
        \draw[black,thick]  (0,1) cos (0.5*pi,0) sin (pi,-1) cos (1.5*pi,0) sin (2*pi,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @Juan Castaño ?

Comment: I don't know what you changed or what you want to change

Comment: How to add picture comment

Comment: Well, I don't know if I understand what you want again (my not so god English to blame). But if you need to add a comment you don't need any changes in the domains. And as you said, there are no `plot`s involved so there are no `domain` options either

Comment: In other order of things, in the node now displaying 'period' you don't need the options `yshift=1mm,text width=2cm` . They were necessary for the original text, longer and extended over two lines, but not in this case

Comment: I mean i want to add picture comment here to exain what i want to do

Comment: Ah!! In the top of the edit box you have several icons. There is one for including pictures

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146762/discussion-between-sophia-n-and-juan-castano).

Answer (score 4):

Now I know what you need. You know, sometimes a picture is worth... clearly a lot if we need a picture XD.

I give you two options:

- If you want something like the linked answer you can `shift` the function (and you need one more `sin`) and `clip` it to the domain [0,2π]:

```
\clip (0,-1.5) rectangle (2*pi,1.5);
\draw[black,thick,shift={(pi/6,0)}] (-0.25*pi,0) sin (0,1) cos (0.25*pi,0) ...
```

- Or, you can `plot` an appropriate function:

```
\draw[red,dashed,thick]  plot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=81] (\x,{cos(deg(2*(\x-pi/6))});
```

I'm drawing the two options overlapped, this way you can see that they give the same output. Chose whatever you prefer.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,xscale=0.75]
  % axes
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)       -- (2*pi+0.5,0) node[right] {$\theta$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,-1.5)    -- (0,1.5)      node[left]  {$Y$};
  % auxiliary lines
  \draw[teal,dashed]      (0,1)       -- (2*pi,1);
  \draw[teal]             (2*pi,-1.5) -- (2*pi,1.5);
  \draw[latex-latex,teal] (0.5*pi,0)  -- (0.5*pi,1)   node[fill=white,midway] {\small amplitude};
  \draw[latex-latex,teal] (0,-1.25)   -- (2*pi,-1.25) node[fill=white,midway] {\small basic interval $2\pi$};
  \draw[latex-latex,teal] (pi,1.4)    -- (2*pi,1.4)   node[fill=white,midway,text width=2cm,align=center]
                                                                              {\small wavelength period cycle};
  % ticks
  \foreach\i in {0.5,1,1.5}
     \draw (\i*pi,0.05) -- (\i*pi,-0.05);
  \foreach\i in {-1,0,+1} 
  \node[left] at (0,\i) {$\i$};
    \node[below]           at (0.5*pi,0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
  \node[below]             at (pi,0)     {$\pi$};
  \node[below]             at (1.5*pi,0) {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
  \node[below,fill=white]  at (2*pi,0)   {$2\pi$};
  % cos (two options, choose whatever you prefer)
  \draw[black,thick] (0,1) cos (0.25*pi,0) sin (0.5*pi,-1) cos (0.75*pi,0) sin (pi,1)
                           cos (1.25*pi,0) sin (1.5*pi,-1) cos (1.75*pi,0) sin (2*pi,1);
  \draw[red,dashed,thick]  plot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=81] (\x,{cos(2*\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,xscale=0.75]
  % axes
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)       -- (2*pi+0.5,0) node[right] {$\theta$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,-1.5)    -- (0,1.5)      node[left]  {$Y$};
  % auxiliary lines
  \draw[teal,dashed]      (0,1)       -- (2*pi,1);
  \draw[teal]             (2*pi,-1.5) -- (2*pi,1.5);
  \draw[latex-latex,teal] (2*pi/3,0)  -- (2*pi/3,1)   node[fill=white,midway] {\small amplitude};
  \draw[latex-latex,teal] (0,-1.25)   -- (2*pi,-1.25) node[fill=white,midway] {\small basic interval $2\pi$};
  \draw[latex-latex,teal] (0,-0.75)   -- (pi/6,-0.75) node[midway,below]      {\small$\frac{\pi}{6}$};
  \draw[teal,dashed]      (pi/6,-1)   -- (pi/6,1);    
  % ticks
  \foreach\i in {0.5,1,1.5}
    \draw (\i*pi,0.05) -- (\i*pi,-0.05);
  \foreach\i in {-1,0,+1}
    \node[left] at (0,\i) {$\i$};
  \node[below]             at (0.5*pi,0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
  \node[below]             at (pi,0)     {$\pi$};
  \node[below]             at (1.5*pi,0) {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
  \node[below,fill=white]  at (2*pi,0)   {$2\pi$};
  % cos (two options, choose whatever you prefer)
  \clip (0,-1.5) rectangle (2*pi,1.5);
  \draw[black,thick,shift={(pi/6,0)}] (-0.25*pi,0) sin (0,1) cos (0.25*pi,0) sin (0.5*pi,-1) cos (0.75*pi,0) sin (pi,1)
                                                             cos (1.25*pi,0) sin (1.5*pi,-1) cos (1.75*pi,0) sin (2*pi,1);
  \draw[red,dashed,thick]  plot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=81] (\x,{cos(deg(2*(\x-pi/6))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try work on them to understand. Thank you so much amigo! 

Comment: You are the best. I got them now